# Custom modal with dropdown in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to show in my modal a select with custom values for my options.
I tried something like that but my html's modal doesn't interact with my script and i don't know how can i do that.

This is my script :

```
function addRow() {
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var widget;
   widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("widget.html");
   ui.showModalDialog(widget, "Add new Row");
   widget.setWidth(600);
   widget.setHeight(600);  
   }


 function getCDC(){
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("BDD");
   var services = feuille.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== "");
   return services.map(d => "<option>" + d[0] + "</option>").join("")
 }
```

And this is my html's page who generate my modal :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Input : <input type="text" id="codeArticle"></p>

     <p>Custom Select :
       <select id="service" name="service" class="form-control" required>
         <option disabled selected>Choose ...</option>
         <?!=getCDC()?>
       </select>
     </p>

     <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT">
     <input type="button" class="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="google.script.host.close();">

   </body>
 </html>
```

If i launch my fonction getCDC(), i obtain what i want ([execution log of this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1r7S.png)).

I don't know where is my problem. This is [the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksS8AkiccbqYyaulc7S8EW4_q_h47c57C-SrZjMdWGs/edit?usp=sharing) of my Sheets if you want to show by yourself. Thank you for advance to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("widget.html");
```

#### To:

```
widget = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("widget.html").evaluate();
```

#### Reference:

- [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename)

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.